# WebRTC multiple simultaneous bitrates

Tags: webrtc

Is there a way in WebRTC to capture video and audio from a user's webcam and stream a low-bitrate version p2p to other users in a "video conference" style app, while simultaneously recording a very high bitrate version (or just very high bitrate audio) that will be saved on my host?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to call `getUserMedia()` multiple times with different resolutions in the same browser: if you try [simpl.info/getusermedia/multi](http://simpl.info/getusermedia/multi), you'll see both video streams have the resolution from the constraints used first.

I haven't tested this, but you might be able to call `getUserMedia()` with HD constraints, and then tweak the b=AS:xx line in the SDP to stream at a lower bitrate. (Take a look at the [unit test](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/talk/app/webrtc/webrtcsdp_unittest.cc#1567) values and the [WebRTC SDP spec](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-nandakumar-rtcweb-sdp/).)

As for recording: the MediaStream Recording API is available in Firefox Nightly (but audio only last time I checked, demo at [simpl.info/mediarecorder](http://simpl.info/mediarecorder/)). There is an [Intent to Implement](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/blink-dev/2l_G_apqk30) in Blink (for Chrome).